# MFC Virtual List Control row height change

Tags: mfc, listctrl

i want to change listCtrl row height

used `OnMeasureItem` for change row height and `OnGetdispinfoListCtrl` for data insert

```
void ShipInfoDlg::OnMeasureItem(int nIDCtl, LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)
{
if(nIDCtl == IDC_LISTCTRL)
{
    LOGFONT lf;
    
    GetDlgItem(IDC_LISTCTRL)->GetFont()->GetLogFont( &lf );

    
    if( lf.lfHeight < 0 )
        lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = -lf.lfHeight + 10;
    else
        lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = lf.lfHeight + 10; 
} 
else CDialog::OnMeasureItem(nIDCtl, lpMeasureItemStruct);
```

}

start this code, winctrl2.cpp Line:593 error

```
void CListCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)
{
ASSERT(FALSE);
}
```

it's that error

i know this problem is in drawItem

but i don`t know solution

thank you

Comment: Suggestion for a simpler approach, but I risk to say a thing which is not really what you want: `SetIconSpacing` may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For an [`LBS_NODATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-box-styles) list box you are responsible for drawing the items by handling the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem) message.

To do so, you will need to provide an implementation for [`DrawItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class#drawitem) in your `CListCtrl`-derived class, as explained in the documentation:

> By default, this member function does nothing. Override this member function to implement drawing for an owner-draw `CListCtrl` object.

The base class implementation, `CListCtrl::DrawItem`, fails with a debug assertion so that the missing implementation won't get easily ignored.